# proxysql - having both hostgroup "-1" and "1"

Tags: mysql, caching, proxysql

I trying to cache query with proxysql with bellow command

```
INSERT INTO mysql_query_rules (active,digest,apply,cache_ttl) VALUES (1,'0x4EFCD2A08D30486D',1, 8640000)
```

after that i get this result from `stats_mysql_query_digest`

can any one help me why i should get two record with diffrent hostgroup?
i think it should be just -1 hostgroup...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The hostgroup -1 is the traffic served directly from the query cache. The queries that are going to hostgroup 1 are because either the results are not present in the cache, or the cache has expired. You can see the amount of successful cache hits
by querying the stats table `stats_mysql_global`, as is explained in the [proxysql documentation](https://proxysql.com/documentation/Query-Cache/).